# What's a good mail server to install on Ubuntu / Apache server?

Tags: email-server

What's a good free mail server to install on Ubuntu / Apache server ?

What's the most diffused one ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exim used to be the default install on Debian. Ubuntu seems to default to postfix now.  I install Exim, as it is easy to configure.  My email server run exim with ACL additions to deal with incoming spam.  (Very little makes it as far as SpamAssassin.)

In your case I would install either Exim or Postfix.  If you aren't going to relay via your ISPs server or another server, you have some DNS configuration which will need to be done.  Check the RFCs and Best Practices.

Answer (score 2):

The standards are generally postfix, exim, or sendmail. personally I'm a fan of exim but that is just me. All of them take some time to get to know and configure but any one of those would be a good choice. I would just pick one and stick with it on all of your servers so you don't have to remember which is installed where.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu+Apache "Postfix or Zimbra" (Zimbra community edition).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should define the question more. Are you talking just simple SMTP or VPOP? 
If simple SMTP, then whatever one is supported by your distribution would be best as it would be well supported. 
If VPOP, then a poptoaster like http://www.qmailtoaster.com/ would be the quickest way.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the most diffused one ?

?

The 'best' program is a very difficult question to answer without doing a lot of research and analysis.

When I'd previously done some field research on this, sendmail was the most reliable MTA I saw traffic through (except for Novell's product - the name of which escapes me temporarily). Postfix a close second, rmail, qmail and exim came down the charts a bit (and MS-Exchange was notably at the bottom).

Sendail is (IMHO) the most configurable, and has the most add ons (have a google for 'milters') but it's also (again, IMHO) the hardest to configure.

As above, Postfix works well and I think its relatively easy to configure / manage.

C.

Answer (score 0):

My vote goes for Postfix. Easy to configure, doesn't require lots of resources, stable, secure and easy to extend.